# Getting Start/End date from multiple rows/single column

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I need to create an output of from/to dates based on start time and end time for each status, in other words when a particular status started and when this status ended, e.g. for record with ID 2 Processing started on 01/04/2019 and ended 01/05/2019 when next status was added.

Here's the sample script:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (ID NUMBER, PARENT_ID NUMBER, STATUS VARCHAR2(20), ADDED_DATE DATE);  
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, PARENT_ID, STATUS, ADDED_DATE) VALUES
(1, 123, 'Requested', TO_DATE('01/01/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, PARENT_ID, STATUS, ADDED_DATE) VALUES
(2, 123, 'Processing', TO_DATE('01/04/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, PARENT_ID, STATUS, ADDED_DATE) VALUES
(3, 123, 'Approved', TO_DATE('01/05/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, PARENT_ID, STATUS, ADDED_DATE) VALUES
(4, 567, 'Requested', TO_DATE('03/12/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, PARENT_ID, STATUS, ADDED_DATE) VALUES
(5, 567, 'Processing', TO_DATE('03/13/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, PARENT_ID, STATUS, ADDED_DATE) VALUES
(6, 4547, 'Requested', TO_DATE('04/22/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, PARENT_ID, STATUS, ADDED_DATE) VALUES
(7, 4547, 'Processing', TO_DATE('04/24/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, PARENT_ID, STATUS, ADDED_DATE) VALUES
(8, 4547, 'On-hold', TO_DATE('04/27/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, PARENT_ID, STATUS, ADDED_DATE) VALUES
(9, 4547, 'Denied', TO_DATE('05/05/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));  
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ID, PARENT_ID, STATUS, ADDED_DATE) VALUES
(10, 15, 'Requested', TO_DATE('03/16/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

Desired output:

```
ID    PARENT_ID     STATUS        FROM_DT        TO_DT  
1     123           Requested     01/01/2019     01/04/2019  
2     123           Processing    01/04/2019     01/05/2019  
3     123           Approved      01/05/2019     SYSDATE  
4     567           Requested     03/12/2019     03/13/2019  
5     567           Processing    03/13/2019     SYSDATE  
6     4547          Requested     04/22/2019     04/24/2019  
7     4547          Processing    04/24/2019     04/27/2019  
8     4547          On-hold       04/27/2019     05/05/2019  
9     4547          Denied        05/05/2019     SYSDATE  
10    15            Requested     03/16/2019     SYSDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest will be to use built-in "Window fuction" `Lead` which allows you to look forward a number of records, in this case just one record. Here's a query which should do the job.

```
SELECT 
  mt.ID,
  mt.PARENT_ID,
  mt.STATUS,
  mt.ADDED_DATE as FROM_DT,
  LEAD(mt.ADDED_DATE, 1, SYSDATE ) OVER (PARTITION BY mt.PARENT_ID ORDER BY mt.ID) as TO_DT
FROM
  mytable mt
ORDER BY
  mt.ID
```

The same result could be achieved in other ways, but this is most efficient. To explain the syntax for `LEAD`:

```
LEAD(mt.ADDED_DATE, 1, SYSDATE)
```

We're getting the value of `ADDED_DATE`, `1` row ahead of the current row within the current group (or Window), and if there is no such row we're returning `SYSDATE`

```
OVER(PARTITION BY mt.PARENT_ID ORDER BY mt.ID)
```

This part defines the group (Window). The LEAD function only works within the group. In our case, what defines a group is the `PARENT_ID`. Different `PARENT_ID`, different group, so you LEAD running on a row for `PARENT_ID = 123` cannot find a value for a `PARENT_ID <> 123`. You can also partition by multiple fields, just separate them by commas. The window will be the set of rows where all those fields agree across the set. As we are looking for the date from the "next row" it's important that the rows are ordered correctly within the window, otherwise looking 1 row ahead might not give you what you're expecting. That's where the `ORDER BY` comes in.

Comment: I have assumed that in your insert the `' '` for the row with `ID=9` is a typo and that it should be `'denied'` as per your desired output. If instead you need to convert that data, you'll need to amend the code a little. Let me know if you need assistance with that.

Comment: Yes, it should have been Denied, I updated the code. Thank you

Comment: Thanks @JKint. Did my answer work for you? If so, do please mark it as the acceptee answer.